# How to internationalize a handlebars + backbone view?

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js, localization, internationalization, handlebars.js

I would like to be able to internationalize a backbone + Handlebars application but I am not clear what the best way to do it. Are there any specific best practices for internationalizing backbone + Handlebar views?

On the server side I am using SpringMVC and have access to standard java internationalization facilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some very good resources on internationalization for the client side.

http://2012.jsconf.eu/speaker/2012/08/28/client-side-internationalization.html really worth watching it provides a good explanation of the issues with internationalization and is java-script focused.

http://alexsexton.com/blog/2012/03/the-ux-of-language/ Good article about the internationalization

JavaScript libraries for internationalization:

- https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js
- http://slexaxton.github.com/Jed/

Standards:

- http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages (very useful read)
- http://cldr.unicode.org/ (more of a reference)

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm working with an app with (very limited) internationalization, and I mix in an object with the model before sending it to the template in the `Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render` function. If you have a similar central function which renders your templates (which I assume you have) you can do this logic there. You could for instance mix the internationalized content (language preselected in) in a namespace, for instance

data = _.extend(model, {t: translations(:dutch))

Leaves how to get the translations from the backend to the frontend, but I don't know enough of SpringMVC to give you advise on that.

Comment: How to do you wit long runs of text that have variables interspersed and possibly markup?

Answer (score 1):

We use i18next (http://i18next.com) in our Require/Backbone/Handlebars app with very good results. It supports plural and context forms and there are converters from PO to JSON and vice versa. (PO is widely used for translations here.) The documentation is clean and full of helpfull examples.

It's possible to use it in Handlebars with both static keys (strings) or dynamic variables. You will have to setup your own Handlebars helpers but the documentation of i18next provides example code for this.

In this post, I've added more implementation details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17728920/621690